# simple form adds div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, semantic-ui

I'm trying to customize simple form (for semantic-ui) by creating my own wrapper. However it looks like simple from keeps adding a div around every input (and wrapper).

```
<div class="float optional recipe_yield">
```

this is my custom wrapper:

```
  config.wrappers :semantic do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder

    b.wrapper tag: :div, class: :field do |c|
      c.use :label_input
    end
  end
```

I expect `f.input :name` to result in this:

```
<div class="field">
  <label class="string optional" for="recipe_name">Name</label>
  <input class="string optional" name="recipe[name]"   id="recipe_name"type="text">
</div>
```

instead i get this:

```
<div class="string optional recipe_name">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="string optional" for="recipe_name">Name</label>
      <input class="string optional" name="recipe[name]"   id="recipe_name"type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i get rid of that extra `<div class="string optional recipe_name">`? I don't want simple form to add that. Or possibly have simple form include 'field' as a class in that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manged to get simple form to add 'field' as one of the classes in the div surrounding the label and input. Basically just have to pass it in as an option when you call config.wrappers.

```
  config.wrappers :semantic, tag: 'div', class: 'field' do |b|
    b.use :html5

    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label_input
  end
```

As you can see I also removed the b.wrapper. Otherwise it will add a div around the label and input but still within

```
<div class="float optional recipe_yield">
```